# Roller rockers to a stock valve train

Tags: engine, chevrolet, valve, sbc

78 Nova but the engine is from a different car; casting # V0707CMH. I have a 350 with 305 heads. Stock valves, pushrods, cam, and lifters. The nuts on my stock rocker arms are in need of replacement; all studs are same height. I was going to just polylock them but thinking of going with roller rockers. This should give a bit more hp; +15 hp.

Do I need to use the guide plates and girdle? And is the stock ratio 1.5 or 1.6?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any pics you can jam up in here?

Comment: Maybe it's different for mobile users.... It doesn't give a photo option. Or I don't know how to.

Comment: I'll check meta and see if there's a way.  I use it to but have never tried to post a pic from it.

Comment: When you edit the question or are writing it fresh there is a bar below the field you are entering the question text in.  To the far right is an icon of a camera where you can pull images from your phone or take an image to post it.

Comment: Is that on the app or via mobile browser? iOS or android?

Comment: On the app.  I just tested it.  I'm using iPhone so I don't know about android.  I would imagine it's the same.

Comment: Ok... Just downloaded app... Won't do it from mobile browser

Comment: ahhhh, ok, I assumed...you know what that means...

Comment: Tried to google your casting code, this is the only instance of that casting code on the internet.

Comment:  V (made in Flint) 0707 (July 7) CMH (1974  350 tur hydro   - 4 A B F)

Comment: Any Chevy dealer will verify my block code

Comment: Off topic this block was made on my birthday... Just not same year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.superchevy.com/how-to/vemp-0703-corvette-rocker-arms/) (and my knowledge, lol) the stock rocker arm ratio of most stock small block Chevy's is 1.5:1. Polylocks should work just fine. Whether you need the guide plates is completely up to what type of roller-rockers you get. If they are non-self aligning (NSA), you'll need the guide plates. If they are self aligning, you won't. My recommendation between the two is to get the NSA type and run the guide plates. The self aligning ones are very noisy. Also, if you go with guide plates, ensure you get ones sized to fit your push rods. You don't want a lot of slop between the guides and the plates or it defeats the purpose.

If you are getting the roller-rockers and don't know how to tell if they are self aligning, here are some images of the two types:

[image]

If you look at the tip of this Scorpion rocker, you'll see what kind of looks like o-rings between the roller tip and the body of the rocker.

[image]

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the same rocker with the one on the left being self-aligning and the one of the right NSA. You can see the small tabs which hang down on either side of the roller tip on the left and the right without. There may be other "types" which will keep the rocker aligned, but this is *kind of* what you'd be looking for.